# css class not having effect in a web page

Tags: css

CSS class at the head section (bodyBackGround class and divLoginBackGround class) of this page is not showing any effect after applying it.  I seriously need help because I 've been battling it for over a day. It used to work before but guess why it is no longer working. Somebody please help. Here is my code below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1 {
            height: 505px;
        }

        .bodyBackGround {
            background: linear-gradient(30deg, Azure, HoneyDew, Lavender);
         }

        .divLoginBackGround {            
            background: repeating-linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(0, 0, 235, 0.4), rgba(0,145,245,0.02), rgba(0,220,255,0.1), rgba(0, 0, 235, 0.02), rgba(0,0,245,0.08), rgba(0,160,255,0.1));
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="bodyBackGround">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="divLoginBackGround" BorderColor="Green" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Style="z-index: 102; left: 319px; position: absolute; top: 158px; width: 392px; height: 228px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Garamond" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 100; left: 42px; position: absolute; top: 142px; width: 63px;" Text="Language:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Garamond" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 100; left: 42px; position: absolute; top: 107px; width: 68px;" Text="Branch:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" runat="server" Style="z-index: 102; left: 120px; position: absolute; top: 137px; height: 22px; width: 206px;" TabIndex="4">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBranch" runat="server" Style="z-index: 102; left: 119px; position: absolute; top: 106px; height: 22px; width: 206px;" TabIndex="3">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Height="24px" Style="z-index: 107; left: 291px; position: absolute; top: 187px; width: 80px; height: 22px;" TabIndex="6" Text="Cancel" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserID" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 119px; position: absolute; top: 43px" TabIndex="1" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 119px; position: absolute; top: 73px" TabIndex="2" Width="201px">*********</asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Style="z-index: 103; left: 16px; position: absolute; top: 10px" Width="284px"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Style="z-index: 104; left: 202px; position: absolute; top: 186px; height: 26px; width: 80px;" TabIndex="5" Text="Login" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Garamond" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 105; left: 42px; position: absolute; top: 72px; width: 62px;">Password:</asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Garamond" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 106; left: 42px; position: absolute; top: 45px">User ID:</asp:Label>
 </asp:Panel>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Works for me, the style rules are applied if I test it locally.

Comment: Clear the cache of your browser and see what happens first.

Comment: works for me too. As Alberto is asking, which browser are you using?

Comment: Thanks a lot. After many failed trials attempt, I try Firefox and Chrome and the css start working on the two browsers. But on ie, it is not working. I am still trying to find how to make it work on ie as well. I will try and research your suggestion of clearing the cache. Thanks greatly.

Comment: I clear the cache by deleting browsing history and yet it is still not working on ie. Thanks to you all for your help.